# How to get the reference of a Application() class in another module?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a multiple module based app, the modules are divided based on the features, I have the Application class in the app module, Now I have a function implemented in the Application class that I would like to use in classes in other modules but I am unable to access it there.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options would be to use dependency injection. 
Using [Koin DI library](https://insert-koin.io/) it would look like this:

```
class YourApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Initialize DI instance from which you will request application context
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@YourApplication)
        }
}
```

Later to retrieve `Application` context or just `Context` you can use `KoinContextHandler`:

```
val koin = KoinContextHandler.get()
val application = koin.get<Application>()
val context = koin.get<Context>()
```

You have to add these dependencies to you `build.gradle` files in app module and another module you use to make it work:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    def koin_version = '2.1.5'
    implementation "org.koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
}
```